# PWA capabilities demonstration

Tags: push-notification, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I would like to ask if you know a source that would demonstrate capabilities of the PWA technology.

Ideally an app that can present particular features on demand (fire push notifications, synchronisations, etc.)?

Imagine that you need to introduce a non-technical client to PWA and give them an example of how it works. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Twitter PWA for this. Besides that it is well known by almost everyone on the Internet, it has the top features for yor PWA "demo" like push notifications, background syncs, etc.

E-commerce talking you could maybe try Aliexpress PWA, I've been using it since the initial prompt at their website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are right. Twitter is a pretty good example. Still, it can't fire push notifications on demand. Please note that the aim is to present it to a non-technical person in the simplest possible way.